# Updating MySQL table - PHP

Tags: php

I'm making a simple auction website and I have a button for the user to click when they wish to bid. The bid is supposed to increment by one, which it seems to do just fine. However, I'm only trying to change the value of my bidprice field. I don't know why, but the code I have is adding new rows with bidhistoryid's that go back by one each time the bidprice go up. I hope I'm being clear enough. Basically, what I need to do is increment my bidprice value by one and nothing more.

This is my code for updating the table. Pretty sure my problem is here.

```
mysql_query("
UPDATE bidhistory
SET bidprice = bidprice + 1
WHERE biditemid = biditemid"
);
```

Comment: UPDATE can't add new rows

Comment: In `WHERE biditemid = biditemid`, is that the exact text of your code, or is the `biditemid` on the right supposed to be a variable?

Comment: @mooiamaduck, That's the exact text.

Answer (score 0):

The clause `WHERE biditemid = biditemid` evaluates to true for all rows in the table (in general, x = x for all x, right?). This query will increment the `bidprice` for all rows in the table every time it is run. This is probably the source of your trouble.

You'll need to parameterize the query based on the id of the item which has been bid on.

Comment: So the biditemid is equal to the itemid, but the itemid is in a different table. Could I still use `WHERE biditemid = itemid`?

Comment: Well, the question is *which* `itemid`. I assume that the `itemid` in question comes from the HTTP request (e.g. via `$_POST`). Once you have the `itemid` you don't need to look it up in the table -- you already know it. All you need to do is interpolate it in the query (and remember to **escape it properly**): ```mysql_query("UPDATE bidhistory SET bidprice = bidprice + 1 WHERE biditemid = " . mysql_escape_string($itemid))```

Comment: Also note that you're using a deprecated mysql API for PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php